# Image doesn't upload in custom module magento

Tags: image, magento, upload

I have created custom module in magento with image upload attribute. Image name was successfully stored in DB table. But image doesn't upload to the target folder.

I have tried with this following code. please show me "what am i doing wrong here"

```
     $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('fileinputname');
     $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
     $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
     $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

     $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') .DS. 'foo'.DS ;
     $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['fileinputname']['name']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last week I added the file upload option for my Magento app..Here is the code. This may help to you. This is the save action for your controller.

```
public function saveAction() {
    $filedata = array();
    $uploadedFile = 'uploaded_file';
    $_helper = Mage::helper('fileuploader');
    if (!empty($_FILES[$uploadedFile]['name'])) {
        try {
            $ext = $_helper->getFileExtension($_FILES[$uploadedFile]['name']);
            $fname = 'File-' . time() . $ext;
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($uploadedFile);
            #$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array("txt", "csv", "htm", "html", "xml", "css", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "rtf", "ppt", "pdf", "swf", "flv", "avi", "wmv", "mov", "wav", "mp3", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png","zip"));

        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom' . DS . 'upload' . DS;

        $uploader->save($path, $fname);

        $filedata[$uploadedFile] = 'custom/upload/' . $fname;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
        return;
    }
}

if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
    $products = array();
    $availProductIds = Mage::getModel('fileuploader/fileuploader')->getAllAvailProductIds();
    parse_str($data['fileuploader_products'], $products);
    foreach ($products as $k => $v) {
        if (preg_match('/[^0-9]+/', $k) || preg_match('/[^0-9]+/', $v)) {
            unset($products[$k]);
        }
    }

    $productIds = array_intersect($availProductIds, $products);
    $data['product_ids'] = implode(',', $productIds);
    if (!empty($filedata[$uploadedFile])) {
        $data[$uploadedFile] = $filedata[$uploadedFile];
    } else {
        if (isset($data[$uploadedFile]['delete']) && $data[$uploadedFile]['delete'] == 1) {
            if ($data[$uploadedFile]['value'] != '')
                $this->removeFile($data[$uploadedFile]['value']);
            $data[$uploadedFile] = '';
        }else {
            unset($data[$uploadedFile]);
        }
    }
    $model = Mage::getModel('fileuploader/fileuploader');
    $model->setData($data)
            ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
    try {
        $model->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('fileuploader')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
            return;
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
        return;
    }
}


Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('fileuploader')->__('Unable to find item to save'));
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

}

Build form by add colomn function in grid.php

```
$this->addColumn('uploaded_file', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('fileuploader')->__('File'),
            'align' => 'left',
            'type' => 'file',
            'escape' => true,
            'sortable' => false,
            'index' => 'uploaded_file',
        ));
```

And This is most important. Dont forgot to mention that your form enctype should be Multi/part in form.php file. I guess you missed it. Please check this.

```
protected function _prepareForm() {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                    'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                    'method' => 'post',
                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
                        )
        );
```

Thats it..!!

Comment: sorry to say this. in " $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom' . DS . 'upload' . DS;" here what is meant by DS?

Comment: Thank you. Its working Fine when i added "'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'" in $form.

Comment: I think you are not familiar with magento modules. Follow this link . Here you can build all type of modules. After build you can download your module and refer source codes that how is it working..

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Comment: Thank you so much. Given link is really nice. Now i have face one more problem. Now that image doesn't save to DB, but image uploaded sucessfully.

Comment: Refer my save action as I mentioned above. And also create some dummy modules with that module creator and check how the things are working..!!

Comment: i have put this setdata " $model->setData($postData);" code before  "$postData['fileinputname'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) .$_FILES['fileinputname']['name'];" so only it didn't save. Now its working good.THank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Hi Elavarasan i can't seem to figure out what is wrong in what i did, or if i actually have done something. I used magento-module-creator you suggested and then added all the code above that you give under helper/data.php. Nothing happens. Appreciate your help as i am new in magento.

Comment: do you get any error or don't have an idea about add image field in admin form? Refer this post http://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/to-add-image-upload-field-in-magento-admin-form/, I hope it would be help you

Comment: I honestly don't have idea about adding image field in manage products under admin. I want to have image upload for thumbnail, small and big image. Confuse where to start. I recently set-up my module -> local/Von/Configs/etc/config.xml and etc/modules/Von_Configs.xml . Will you be so kind to instruct me how to implement the above code shared by Elavarasan? Where and which folder to access? I am using enterprise version. Thanks

Comment: Also the post you gave me. I can't seem to find  /app/code/local/Chilly/ModName/Block/Adminhtml/ModName/Edit/Form.php

Comment: YOu can follow the above blog post. I have explained there about add image field to admin form completely.

Comment: Then where to create a form in your module?

Comment: now i'm lost.I have my indexController where i call contact.phtml.